# Call jquery function from another view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, spring-mvc

I have a jquery function 'ShowerrorDialog' in view named index.cshtml and I need to call the same function from another view test.cshtml.

```
function ShowerrorDialog(msg) {
        $("#errorDialog").html(msg);
        $("#errorDialog").dialog({ modal: true, 
        dialogClass:'errorDialogClass',
         buttons: {
                 "OK" : function() {
                                $( "#errorDialog" ).dialog("close");
                                }
                   }
                   });
    }
```

test.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Ad_hocReporting.Models.GridModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@{

    if (@Model.First().message == "Session Out")
    {
        //need to call ShowerrorDialog here
    }
    else
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "popup_content", rowsPerPage: 7);
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
    <div id="popup_content">
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", rowStyle: "webGridRow", headerStyle: "webGridHeader", footerStyle: "webgridFooter", alternatingRowStyle: "webGridAlternateRow", columns: grid.Columns(

                                                   grid.Column("QueryTitle", (format: @<label>@item.QueryTitle</label>), header: "Query Name", style: "color:gray"),
                                        grid.Column((format: @<a href="#" onclick="javascript:OnEdit(this.id,'@item.QueryTitle');" class="selectcss" id=@item.QueryId>Select</a>), header: "Select"),
                                       grid.Column((format: @<input type="image" src="../../Content/images/DeleteRed.png" alt="delete" class="deletecss" onclick="javascript:OnDelete(this.id);" id=@item.QueryId'delete' />), header: "Delete")))
    </div>
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you keep that function in a common js file and refer the file from wherever you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the function in a generic file and use the tag `include` for use it.

Comment: This should be in comment